# Scala Linearization in resolving super

Tags: scala, traits

I have coded as follow :

```
trait Base1 {
    def print() { println("Base1") }
}

trait A extends Base1 {
    override def print() { println("A"); super.print() }
}

trait B extends Base1 {
    override def print() { println("B"); super.print() }
}

class Base2 {
    def print() { println("Base2") }
}

class C extends Base2 with A with B {
    override def print() { println("C"); super.print() }
}

object Main extends App {
    (new C).print()
}
```

I applied the linearization and found the order as

```
c >> B >> A >> Base1 >> Base2 >> AnyRef >> Any
```

I got following output

**C**

**B**

**A**

**Base1**

However Base2 print function is not being called . what am i missing here ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at your linearization chain, your chain of `super` calls ends at `Base1` which does not call `super.print()`. Therefore the next thing up the linearization chain, namely `Base2` never gets its `print` method called.

Amusingly it's also impossible for `Base1` to call `super.print` because it could be mixed into classes which don't linearize in a way such as to give `Base` an ancestor with a compatible `print` method. So you're stuck with `Base2` not being able to print itself out.